# Why the default constructor must be provided in spring-data

Tags: java, spring-data

I know if I do not implement the default constructor in a spring data an exception will be thrown,actually I faced the same exception when I have to work databases. I never understand the reason. Please advise

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: because spring needs to be able to create an instance of your class and set the variables via reflection or setters. If you do not provide a default constructor there is no clean way for the framework to create an instance because what values are they supposed to pass in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, for clarity, it's not the [*default* constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) (you never explicitly implement the default constructor, that's why it's called a default), it's the zero-parameters constructor. (E.g., the one that [`Class#newInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--) would call.)

You need to implement it in most object/relational mappers because they first create the object (with the zero-parameters constructor) and then assign its individual field values to it.

Having said that, if you don't implement *any* constructors, then the default constructor the compiler will provide should be sufficient for most OR mappers (I haven't used spring-data). By default, it's a zero-parameters constructor with the same accessibility as the class. But if you implement any constructors, the compiler won't create the default for you, and you'd have to supply the zero-parameters constructor yourself.